# How to spin a number of EC2 instances in different corresponding subnets using ANSIBLE?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible, ansible-2.x

I am trying to spin a number of EC2 instance using Ansible in different availability zone and hence subnets, what i am confused here is how can i pass the right subnet corresponding to the right zone?

Assume i am passing my subnet variables as :

```
subnet_id_a: "subnet-9c3e38f8"
subnet_id_b: "subnet-88d171ff"
```

now these subnets are in different az's , i need to create some n number of instances which needs to be spun of in different AZ's

I am trying to use:

```
  - name: Create ES Master Node instances
    ec2:
      key_name: "{{ aws_key_name }}"
      instance_type: "{{ aws_instance_type }}"
      image: "{{ aws_ami }}"
      wait: yes
      wait_timeout: 500
      count: "{{ master_instance_count }}"
      instance_tags:
        Name: "{{ master_tag_name }}"
      volumes:
        - device_name: /dev/sda1
          volume_type: gp2
          volume_size: 100
      vpc_subnet_id: "{{ subnet_id }}"
      zone: "{{ aws_region }}{{ item.0 }}"
      region: "{{ aws_region }}"
      group: "{{ aws_sec_group_name }}"
    with_items:
      - [ 'a' , 'b']
    register: ec2_details
```

But i am not sure how can pass the corresponding subnets according to this so that each instance gets spun in different az? please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refactor variable like this:

```
subnet_ids:
  a: subnet-9c3e38f8
  b: subnet-88d171ff
```

And in your task:

```
...
vpc_subnet_id: "{{ subnet_ids[item] }}"
...
with_items: [a, b]
```

I suppose `zone` is not necessary, because subnet is already bound to some AZ.
And you don't need to nest your loop list like this `- [a, b]`, use just `[a, b]` to avoid `item.0`.

Comment: But somehow this is creating 6 instances when i pass instance count as 3 , i.e 3 in subnet a and 3 in subnet b

Comment: also this screws up my later parts of play where i am trying to use  "{{ ec2_details.instances }}"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48514477/creating-instance-and-tagging-via-ansible 

Please see ^^